# Only getting part of Depth sensor image?

Tags: kinect

- The image on the LEFT is from the Kinect SDK sample which is working correctly.
- The image on the RIGHT is from my C# console application which saves images to a folder. It's sort of working because I can see the top of my head being saved. However I would like the full image like on the left.

I would put some code but I wouldn't know where to start.

Any idea what could cause this? Anything that could point me in the right direction would help.

[image: Only managing to get a part of Kinects view]

Comment: It looks like you are getting the correct image, just not all of it. So how about starting with the code that gets the image from the sensor?

Comment: Looks like i'll have to backtrack and see what's wrong. What's strange is that there are no parameters that I put in or the demo that say what the viewport size is.

Comment: Without your code it will be hard to help. You could check your code against the depth basic sample.